# Error: "Reference does not exist" when using a custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cheerio, referenceerror

I'm trying to **scrape** a webpage & to put the value in cache in order to not hit the daily urlFetch limit.

This is the code I'm using, it works without the Cache & Properties service but not when I try to add that element.

```
function scrapercache(url) {
  var url = "https://www.gurufocus.com/term/fscore/nyse:ABBV/Piotroski-F-Score";
  var result = [];
    var description;
    var options = {
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'followRedirects': false,
    };
Logger.log('line 16 OK');
  
var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
Logger.log('line 21 OK');
 
  let res = cache.get(url);
//  if(res){
 // return JSON.parse(res)
//}
Logger.log(res);
Logger.log('line 24 OK');

  if (res) {
    // trim url to prevent (rare) errors
    url.toString().trim();
    var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(r);
    Logger.log('line 34 OK');
    
    var c = r.getResponseCode();
    Logger.log(c);
    Logger.log('line 38 OK');

    // check for meta refresh if 200 ok
    if (c == 200) {
      var html = r.getContentText();
      cache.put(url, "cached", 21600);
      properties.setProperty(url, html);
      Logger.log('line 46 OK');

      var $ = Cheerio.load(html); // make sure this lib is added to your project!
      Logger.log('line 49 OK');

      // meta description
      if ($('meta[name=description]').attr("content")) {
        description = $('meta[name=description]').attr("content").trim();
        var trim_des = description.substr(0, 40);
        Logger.log('line 55 OK');
      }
    }
  
    result.push([trim_des]);   
    Logger.log('line 60 OK');
  }

  return result;
  Logger.log('line 64 OK');
}
```

I call the function like that:

```
=scrapercache("https://www.gurufocus.com/term/fscore/nyse:ABBV/Piotroski-F-Score")
```

& I get the following error message

> Error: Reference does not exist

[image: Google Sheets screenshot]

EDIT: I added log lines to see if the script was processing correctly & it looks like it's ok only until like 28

[image: script log screenshot]

Comment: Which line throws the error? See [mcve]

Comment: Hi TheMaster, it doesn't specify which line throws an error. When I run the script in the script editor, I get no error message.

Sorry, I'm very new to coding so I'm not sure how to do a minimal reproducible example because I'm not sure which part we need to test.

Thank you

Comment: Where do you see the error?  Screenshot pls

Comment: Sorry, I can't upload a screenshot on my comment.

I get the error message when I call the function like that in the Google Sheets

=scrapercache("https://www.gurufocus.com/term/fscore/nyse:ABBV/Piotroski-F-Score")

Comment: also, possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925773/eliminate-ref-reference-does-not-exist-issue and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575997/reference-does-not-exist-error-google-script

Comment: Upload by [edit]ing your question

Comment: Oh thanks, I just uploaded the Google Sheets screenshot when I call the function with the error message

Comment: @OlegValter: thanks for the 2 links, I checked them & I don't understand how this can help me. They are about GetRange & Arrays

Comment: @Gabriel - thank you for checking them. That is why I did not vote to close as duplicate. That said, usually the same error message is produced by the same underlying issue, although you might think that is different. Could you please log what is the value of the `result`  in the finally clause? And also: doeas the script reach past `var $ = Cheerio.load(html);` [when run as a custom function]? Note that editor and custom function in a sheet are two different execution contexts, so what works in one may not work in other

Comment: @OlegValter: sorry but how can I log the value of  ```result``` please?
Also, how can I see if the script passes a line or not?
When I run the script, I don't get any error message. 
As you said, I realized running the script or calling the function doesn't work the same.
Thanks again

Comment: @Gabriel - both questions: by `console.log`-ing :) Also, try logging the `error` and check the execution log

Comment: is it a line to add in the script?
I went to the menu View -> Logs in Google Script Editor but no log available even after running the function :(

Comment: @Gabriel - yes, this is a statement (but you are on the right track - you will still need to check the logs afterwards)

Comment: @OlegValter. How/where can I check the log in Google Script editor after running the script please?

Comment: @OlegValter: OK I understood I need to add line of code to log
So I added several Logger.log('line OK') to see if processing  & it looks like it's stopping at line 28. I updated the code in the question + the screenshot

Comment: @Gabriel - apologies, I just saw your response. Actually, it is likely to break at `var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);`. Please, log what `res` holds

Comment: @OlegValter, no worries, I was sleeping, I'm in Asia.
I added the log for res with  Logger.log(res);
and it looks like the value is null from the log: [20-07-16 07:10:32:070 HKT] null
so there is probably an issue with var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
Thank you

Comment: @Gabriel - hm, if it is `null`, then the `if` statement block should execute, which should incdicate that the `UrlFetchApp` may cause issues here. Try logging `r` as well, just for the sake of it.

Comment: @OlegValter: the ```if``` statement block executes is res is not null, no? ```if (!res)```
I added log for ```r``` & ```c``` but we can't see them because the ```if``` doesn't go through.

[20-07-16 08:13:24:523 HKT] line 19 OK
[20-07-16 08:13:24:565 HKT] line 24 OK
[20-07-16 08:13:24:613 HKT] null
[20-07-16 08:13:24:616 HKT] line 28 OK
[20-07-16 08:13:34:171 HKT] line 72 OK

Comment: @Gabriel - contrary to what you might think, `null` is falsy :) `!null` is actually `true`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Reference does not exist" error when executing a custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575997/reference-does-not-exist-error-when-executing-a-custom-function)

Answer (score 2):

You're not putting the results in the cache, you're putting the string "cached" there. Consider:

```
let cached = cache.get(url)
if(cached){
  return JSON.parse(cached)
}

let results =  ["blah","blah"] // stuff we got with cheerio
cache.put(url, JSON.stringify(results), 120)
return results
```

Comment: shouldn't the OP's code reach `Logger.log('line 37 OK');` then in the first place? I am concerned that if the `Logger.log('line 28 OK');` call is reached, but not the former, what else might be the cause expect `UrlFetchApp` (really curious)?

Comment: @oleg It won't reach there if it's in the cache.

Comment: true, I am confused, though, because OP stated that the `res` is `null`, therefore the script should enter the `if` block at least. If you are correct, I see the problem - the "reference not exist" error is caused by returning an empty array in most cases. I think this Q&A should be closed as duplicate then if the OP can confirm, thank you!

Comment: Sorry guys, you lost me here. 
@pguardiario: could you edit my code with your suggestion please? Not sure how to properly put your input in my code
OlegValter: please don't close the question, my problem is still not solved.
Thanks both

Comment: @Gabriel - please don't mind closure note, this is about guiding users to the Q&As that have the solution to the problem you describe, it is not that we "close" something as you would expect a support ticket. You just need to make sure that: A. you actually return `res` if it is cached. Currently, on success you simply return an empty array, which leads to the error (and that is why the question is duplicate, btw). B. put `html` to cache as pguardiario suggested, not the `cached` string.

Comment: I recommend to cache the parsed results actually as html might be too big

Comment: @pguardiario: I tried to add your recommendation with JSON.parse like that ```  let res = cache.get(url);
//  if(res){
 // return JSON.parse(res)
//}``` but I get the following error: ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0 (line 26, file "Code")```

Comment: @Gabriel - that is expected, currently, your cache has a `cached` string saved into it, hence when `JSON` tries to parse, it encounters an invalid JSON string. Also: pguardiario's idea, if I understood correctly (correct me if I am wrong), is to not save the html anywhere, only the results of the scrape (since you are after them in the first place)

Comment: @Oleg: I don't need the full meta description, only the first 40 or 50 characters.
Should I empty the cache with the ```cached``` string in it? If yes, how?
Otherwise, what should I modify?

Comment: see my comment under my answer ^

Answer (score 2):

**Error: “Reference does not exist”**

This error message is usually returned by calling a custom function in a spreadsheet cell that *does not return a value*. It is explicitly mentioned by the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values), but the error message is not provided, so the confusion is understandable.

An empty array is not a valid return value (since there are no elements to return). The error is easily reproducible with the following custom function:

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 */
function testReferenceError() {
  const list = [];

  return list;
}
```

Which, when called in a cell, resulting in the "desired" error:

[image: reference error screenshot]

**Applied to your case**

In your situation, when there is a cached data in `cache`, the `if` statement clause evaluates to `false` ([truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value when negated evaluates to `false`). When it does, nothing gets `push`ed to the `result`, and an empty array is returned in `finally` (see above for the explanation of consequences). Consider this mock:

```js
const cache = {
  get() {
    return "cached";
  }
};

let res = cache.get("mock_url");

//ternary operator here acts the same as "if...else":
console.log( !res ? "will enter if block" : "will enter else block" );
```

---

Note on `return` in finally: If you put a return statement into a `finally` block, [expect it to *override*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Description) the `return` statements in `try` or `catch`. Consider this example close to how your program is structured:

```js
const final = (add = false) => {
  const list = [];
  
  try {
    add && list.push(1);
   
    return [1,2]; //this return is skipped
  }
  catch(error) {
    list.push(error);
  }
  finally {
    return list;
  }
  
};

console.log( final() );
```

Also, the question already [has an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30584209/11407695)

Comment: Thanks guys.
I tried to update the script remove the ```try``` ```catch``` ```finally```
& changing the condition to ```if (res)``` but now I get another error in the log.
I updated the script & the screenshot in the post question. 
Sorry again, I'm not very good at coding. I checked the other answer but I don't see how it can help me :(
Thank you

Comment: @Gabriel - you are close, but you overdid it - why would you want to fetch the data *if* it is in cache, don't you want ot return it right away? No need to change from `!res`. Also - remind me, why do you need both PropertiesService *and* the cache?

Comment: If I put back !res in the if. When I run the script & check the log, I get that:
[20-07-16 18:06:04:988 HKT] line 16 OK
[20-07-16 18:06:04:994 HKT] line 21 OK
[20-07-16 18:06:05:038 HKT] false
[20-07-16 18:06:05:040 HKT] line 24 OK

so it's not entering the if statement.
What should I change then?
Thanks

Comment: @Gabriel - that's expected, don't worry. You have a `"cached"` string saved into cache (from your previous attempts). Take a look at [`remove`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#remove(String)) or removeAll, clear the cache, then rerun the script without it. Side note: `Logger.log('line 64 OK');` will never be logged, everything after `return` is essentially lost

Comment: in order to clear the cache, I tried ```cache.removeAll('cached');``` or ```cache.removeAll();``` on line 24 but I get error message ```Parameters don't match the method signature``` I removed the log on line 67

Comment: please, take note of the number of the type and number of parameters... A single string is removed via `remove`, not `removeAll`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217953/discussion-between-gabriel-and-oleg-valter).